# How to create rectangle blocks inside JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, parsing, jpanel, jtextfield

Hello I have a problem creating a cache simulator.

I created a panel in witch I want to draw `nrofblocks` blocks each with `blocksize` lines.

I don't know what is the best way to do this, that is why I am asking for help.

```
private static final int LEN = 1024;
/*...*/
int blocksize = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
int nrofblocks = LEN/blocksize;

JPanel block_panel = new JPanel();
block_panel.setBounds(140, 16, 534, 398);
getContentPane().add(block_panel);
```

Comment: Why not instead of JPanels use Rectangle class, Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400003/how-to-draw-shapens-inside-shapes-solved-new-how-to-create-arraylist-to-use/11400592#11400592). It will give you more control over drawing etc

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at `GridLayout` and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) is a tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: +1 for using a lyaout. Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9858355/230513).